# How to add a Button in kendo pop up

Tags: button, kendo-ui, popup

![kendo popup][1]

How to add a button to view details in the kendo popup UI
Like Update, Cancel button. I want to add one more button in that popup

Comment: You mean the kendo notification or the kendo window?

Comment: not like that. I need to add the one more button in the kendo popup window. When clicking that button it need to show the table or form within the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a HTML for a confirmation modal dialog

```
<div data-role="modalview" id="confirmationView" data-init="app.confirmationView.onInit" style="display: none;">
    <p class="message" data-bind="text: confirmationText"></p>
    <hr>
    <p>
        <a data-role="button" class="buttonYes" data-bind="click: onYesClick">Yes</a>
        <a data-role="button" class="buttonNo" data-bind="click: onNoClick">No</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

And that is ViewModel for it (a requireJs module)

```
/*global define*/
define(['kendo', 'jquery'], function (kendo, $) {
    'use strict';
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        callback: undefined,
        confirmationText: '',
        onInit: function () {
            kendo.bind('#confirmationView', viewModel);
        },
        onYesClick: function () {
            if (typeof viewModel.callback === 'function') {
                viewModel.closeConfirm();
                viewModel.callback(true);
            } else {
                viewModel.closeConfirm();
            }

        },
        onNoClick: function () {
            if (typeof viewModel.callback === 'function') {
                viewModel.callback(false);
            }
            viewModel.closeConfirm();
        },
        onCloseClick: function() {
            viewModel.closeConfirm();
        },
        showConfirm: function(text, callback) {
            viewModel.callback = callback;
            viewModel.set('confirmationText', text);
            $("#confirmationView").show().data().kendoMobileModalView.open();
        },
        closeConfirm: function () {
            $("#confirmationView").data().kendoMobileModalView.close();
        }
    });

    return viewModel;
});
```

To show confirmation dialog you can just call showConfirm from this module